# Why flower's HTTP API get task info not work?

Tags: celery, flower

I have a working celery flower project. 
Now I want some celery task details using flower http api,but when I make a request at flower http api on http://localhost:5555/api/task/info/`task_id` it return 500 error?

Everything is all right in flower page.

[image]

While using requests to get http api, something error happened!

[image]

All of the steps are followed [Flower's documentation](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#get--api-task-types). The Flower logging as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For flower 0.9.2, it tries to put each attribute of `task._fields` into the response:

```
def get(self, taskid):
    ...
    response = {}
    for name in task._fields:
        if name not in ['uuid', 'worker']:
            response[name] = getattr(task, name, None)
    response['task-id'] = task.uuid
    if task.worker is not None:
        response['worker'] = task.worker.hostname
    self.write(response)
```

Turns out there are Task object in `task._fields` like `parent`, `root`:

```
class Task(object):
    ...
    _fields = (
        ...
        'clock', 'client', 'root', 'root_id', 'parent', 'parent_id', 'children',
    )
```

In celery, these fields have specific serialize handlers:

```
self._serializer_handlers = {
    'children': self._serializable_children,
    'root': self._serializable_root,
    'parent': self._serializable_parent,
}
```

While in flower, it just pass it to `self.write` and it doesn't know how to serialize those objects.

I think it has been fixed in flower 1.0.0:

```
def get(self, taskid):
    ...
    response = task.as_dict()
    if task.worker is not None:
        response['worker'] = task.worker.hostname

    self.write(response)
```

In `as_dict` function, the serialization is delegated to celery if available or use default keys:

```
def as_dict(task):
    # as_dict is new in Celery 3.1.7
    if hasattr(Task, 'as_dict'):
        return task.as_dict()
    # old version
    else:
        return task.info(fields=task._defaults.keys())
```

Version 1.0.0 is still in development but you can install it from git repo by running `pip install git+https://github.com/mher/flower.git`.

Comment: Thanks, it's solved. Conda's version was not the latest.